# Javascript: Limit array around index

Tags: javascript

I have a array of videos uploaded by a user that I want limit the length of. However, I want the videos limited to reflect the position of the current video instead of just removing videos from the start or end of the array. For example:

If the video is the first video uploaded by a uploader with more than 100 videos

```
* The video
- The 99 next videos
```

If the video is the 200th video uploaded by a uploader with 1,300 videos

```
- Videos 150-199
* The video (video 200)
- Videos 201-250
```

If the video is the 70th video uploaded by a uploader with 100 videos

```
- Videos 1-69
* The video (video 70)
- Videos 71-100
```

If the video is the last video uploaded by a uploader with 300 videos

```
- Videos 200-299
* The video (video 300)
```

My current code does not quite do this correctly. Assuming there are 300 videos, if the video is at the start I get videos 1-100 returned, but if the video is at the end I get videos 250-300 returned instead of 200-300.

```
export const limitVideos = (videosList, index, limit = 100) => {
    let least = index - Math.floor(limit / 2);
    least = (least < 0) ? 0 : least;
    return videosList.slice(least, least + limit);
};
```

How can I fix my code to limit videos this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const limitVideos = (videosList, index, limit = 3) => {
    let least = index - Math.floor(limit / 2);
    
    let len = videosList.length
    if(least + limit > len)
        least = len - limit

    least = (least < 0) ? 0 : least;
    
    return videosList.slice(least, least + limit);
};
```

The reason of returning result [250, 300] instead of [200, 300] that's because the least is set 250 as you know, so I add the if-state for handling when the index is at the end of videosList

Answer (score 0):

you see if the least value was smaller than 0 or the max value outof videoList length, you can't get return value of lenght 'limit', these edge conditins should be considered,please try this:

```
export const limitVideos = (videosList, index, limit = 100) => {
const maxIndex = videosList.length - 1
if(index > maxIndex || index < 0) {
    return false
}

if(videosList.length <= limit) {
    return videosList
}

let least = index - Math.floor(limit / 2);
let max;
if(least < 0) {
    max = limit - 1;
    least = 0;
} else {
    if(least + limit - 1 > maxIndex) {
        max = maxIndex
        least = least - (least + limit - 1 - maxIndex)
    } else {
        max = least + limit - 1;
        least = least
    }
}
return videosList.slice(least, max + 1);   
}
```

if there are still problems please let me know